# What is Uniform Civil Code?

Tags: india, legislative-process, executive-order

India wants to bring Uniform Civil Code into the country. Current Narendra Modi Government has mentioned in their manifesto as well for the implementation for the UCC. One of the state in Goa has already implemented this.

Question :

What is Uniform Civil Code and Why is it tough for the government to introduce UCC to other states in India like Goa ?

Comment: Please make your q more focused. I count 4 question marks and 3 close votes...

Comment: Besides, there's a lengthy Wikipedia article https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Uniform_Civil_Code

Answer (score 8):

India is a culturally divided country, especially along religious lines. For things like property rights, legality of marriage, and other *civil* matters (as opposed to criminal law), citizens are subject to different sets of laws dependent upon their religious affiliation, or other community designation.

The UCC is a proposal to establish a single set of laws for all citizens and residents of India, regardless of religion or community; essentially bringing their civil code's jurisdiction in line with that of their criminal code.

The benefits of this are numerous but there's three main points:

1. Simplicity - A single set of laws makes determining what laws apply to a given person much easier to determine, and everyone can go about with the same set of expectations.
2. Sovereignty - As it stands now, civil law in India is dependent upon religious traditions, rather than the authority of the Indian government. Establishing a UCC reinforces that law is the domain of the government of India, instead of religious authorities which may or may not draw influences from foreign lands.
3. Anti-discrimination/Anti-oppression - A big selling point for the UCC among its proponents is that this will help to outlaw and curtail oppression of vulnerable minorities who, because of their religious affiliation, etc., are currently not entitled to civil law protections, despite being full Indian citizens.

The downsides are largely dependent on who you are and how well the status quo is working for you, but a period of legal uncertainty and instability will result as would happen from any major change in the legal landscape.  This new system will take some getting used to.

Most other democratic nations, and a whole host of other nations besides, have something that looks like the UCC (though they don't call it that, per se).  In most nations you have a single set of laws that applies to all citizens/residents, with occasional carve-outs for certain positions or conditions. India's civil law *lassez faire* is one of the relatively unique things about India.

As for why it is difficult, any major overhaul of an existing status quo is, politically speaking, a tall order. The fact that one of the earliest proponents for a uniform civil law was the British Crown likely doesn't help the optics here, either, however.

Comment: The US does have a UCC; it might be worth mentioning it briefly, especially how it is a guideline rather than binding law.  Would India's UCC similarly be a guideline or would it be binding?

Comment: @phoog It's not just the US, so I feel like it's covered under "most other democratic nations..." The idea that the law should apply equally is fairly common.  As to the specifics of India's UCC, it's still very much a proposal, and so subject to changes in a big way. I don't feel comfortable trying to summarize the many different understandings of it.

Comment: But the US UCC doesn't apply equally (and in fact, now that I think of it, the US UCC is the "uniform commercial code," not the "uniform civil code," so maybe it's irrelevant).  What federal countries currently have a uniform civil code?

Comment: @phoog The 5th and 14th Amendments (aka the due process clause) apply to civil cases in the United States - this establishes the constitutional principle that a citizen of the United States is a citizen of the United States and enjoys equal legal status as such with other citizens. I thought you were talking about this in your original comment. (citation: https://law.justia.com/constitution/us/amendment-14/05-procedural-due-process-civil.html)

Comment: @phoog As to other nations, one example is the European Convention on Human Rights (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/European_Convention_on_Human_Rights#Article_1_%E2%80%93_respecting_rights) wherein signatories grant various rights - many of which are civil - to "human beings" which has similar effect.

Comment: Ok, but that establishes broad guidelines. The specific elements of specific civil torts may vary from one state to the next.

Comment: The Uniform Commercial Code (adopted independent by separate states in the U.S. and not actually perfectly uniform) is not equivalent to a Uniform Civil Code, which would be more analogous to the French or German civil code.

Comment: I buy points 1 and 2 but I don't get point 3. How is their discrimination for the protection of citizens possible on the basis of religion in india as per the law ? Can you cite some examples ?

Comment: @MichaelHarvey Your statement is quite... irrelevant. Also, it's quite a misconception and over-generalization that all Hindus don't eat beef. Especially in Kerala and parts of the North-East, there are a lot of Beef-eating Hindus. It's the recent political climate that vehemently opposes beef.

Comment: @MichaelHarvey Figures. So, do quite a few of my Malayali friends. Although I still don't understand how that joke/statement is relevant to the UCC/this answer.

Comment: @MichaelHarvey I am not a fan of Modi's politics, but still your statements are unnecessary and inflammatory to a large set of people.